# Postgresql: sort by lastet in a group disregarding of other values in group and without actual "group by"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a series of events per object and want to sort per event time but grouping all related to the same object events together, like:

```
event_id event_date object_id
 11      2021-03-01    3
 12      2021-02-01    3
 13      2018-01-01    3
 21      2021-02-20    2
 22      2019-10-22    2
 31      2021-01-30    1
```

Item 21 is below items 11,12,13 because the latest date is for object_id 3, then for object 2, than for object 1.

I couldn't figure out syntax without some complex CTE and joins...

Probably there is something built-in as I thing it is common requirement for reports (to sort by date but group related items together).

**UPDATE** Based on @Gordon answer:

```sql
with tbl(event_id, event_date, object_id) as (values
  (11, date '2021-03-01', 3), (12, date '2021-02-01', 3), (13, date '2018-01-01', 3),
  (21, date '2021-02-20', 2), (22, date '2019-10-22', 2),
  (31, date '2021-01-30', 1))
select * from tbl
order by max(event_date) over (partition by object_id) desc, object_id, event_date;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions in the `order by`:

```
order by max(event_date) over (partition by object_id) desc,
         object_id,
         event_date desc
```

The first key calculates the maximum event date for each object.  The middle separates objects that have the same maximum date.  The third key orders within the group.

Comment: Tnx! I expected that there is something built-in regarding the question. I checked docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/queries-order.html It mentions: *The sort expression(s) can be any expression that would be valid in the query's select list*. It is difficult to infer that window functions are included ))

Comment: @gavenkoa . . . You can even use subqueries.  But particularly disconcerting are set returning functions, such as `generate_series()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can join objects_last_date subquery and order according it:

```
SELECT 
  events.event_id, events.event_date, events.object_id
FROM 
  events
  JOIN (
    SELECT object_id, 
      MAX(event_date) as last_date 
    FROM events
    GROUP BY object_id ) AS objects_last_date ON events.object_id = objects_last_date.object_id
ORDER BY
  last_date, events.event_date, events.event_id
```